# Vite + Vue 3 + AWS build

Tags: amazon-web-services, vuejs3, aws-sdk, vite

I'm trying to deploy a Vue 3 application that uses Vite, which locally works perfectly, but after deploy I get this error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'memoizedProperty')`

I read that it could be from `aws-sdk` not collaborating well with Rollup, but it seems that the other solutions on the internet haven't worked.

Here are the relevant parts from `vite.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
      alias: {
        // vue: '@vue/compat'
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
        path: 'path-browserify',
        // 'aws-sdk': 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk.min.js',
        './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser', // fix production build
      },
    },
```

This is one of the threads I've been following: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1769

How can I make sure this works?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?